# jQuery pausing between each animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery's simple method of animating and a rotate function using jQuery's animation methods to create a moving `div ("#box")`.

```
    function AnimateRotate(d, div, del){

        var elem = $(div);

        $({deg: 0}).delay(del).animate({deg: d}, {
            duration: 2000,
            step: function(now){
                elem.css({
                     transform: "rotate(" + now + "deg)"
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

...

```
        AnimateRotate(360, "#box", 0)


        $("#box").animate(

        {

            top : "400px",
            left : "400px",
            width : "250px",
            height : "120px"

        },2000, function() {.....
```

This works perfectly, except this will only move my `div` from it's original location to the newly set location.

I would like it to make a spiral movement so I need the div to move one location, to another, to  another, to another....

To do this I tried:

```
        AnimateRotate(360, "#box", 0)


        $("#box").animate(

        {

            top : "400px",
            left : "400px",
            width : "250px",
            height : "120px"

        },2000, function() {

            AnimateRotate(360, "#box", 0)


            $("#box").animate(

            {

                top : "200px",
                left : "200px",
                width : "250px",
                height : "100px"

            },2000, function() {.....
```

And so on till I have about  or 6 different locations. But between each animation there s a little pause which basically ruins the whole animation.

What I'd like to know is if there is a way to prevent this pause?

If not, are there any better ways to do this type of animation? 
Even if it means losing the div altogether and using some other type of shape animation.

Please let me know what te best way to approach this is.

Thanks a lot for any answers.

Comment: I wonder if the easing used is causing this as IIRC jQuery defaults to 'swing' which speeds up then slows down. Try setting it to 'linear', which will run at a constant speed. Also, could you post an example fiddle?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: have you tried setting queue:false and firing them using a setTimeout with 0 value?

Comment: sorry for the delay, i had to familiarize myself with jsfiddle. 
Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/tJgS5/33/

Comment: you will notice the pause between both rotations

Comment: Using `linear` didn't seem to fix it. This type of animation would be perfect with CSS3 animations if you're willing to use them

Comment: Could you explain to me how to use the CSS animations, and are they compatible with firefox, chrome and IE9 ?

Comment: The pauses only happen in firefox.  It looks fine in chrome and IE 10 after switching to linear: http://jsfiddle.net/tJgS5/36/  if you want a totally smooth animation, you should consider doing the animation steps yourself and integrating all the properties you need into it rather than doing multiple animations.

Comment: To answer your other question, CSS animations and transitions are not available in IE 9, only IE 10+.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that worked perfectly. I can't think of any other way of doing the spiral animation path without doing separate animations like I did. If it was a straight path I could do one animation, but not with a circular path.